# TFS 2008, Conchango Scrum For Team Systems, and Work Item Queries

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, wiql

We are using the first version of Scrum for team system in TFS 2008.  What I'm trying to do is write a query to get all sprint backlog items in the current active sprint.  I'd like to use the sprint start and end dates around the @Today param to get the list.

something like this:

```
Team Project = @Project
AND Sprint Start <= @Today
AND Sprint End >= @Today
```

This query returns only the Sprint.  I want all the sprint backlog items.  I almost need to be able to do a subquery

```
Team Project = @Project
AND Sprint Number IN (Sprint Start <= @Today AND Sprint End >= @Today)
```

Anyone have any ideas?  Right now I just have

```
Team Project = @Project
AND Sprint Number <= 12
```

and I really hate the idea of having to change the number across all my queries every time we start a new sprint.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying to find a more elegant solution myself. One convulted way is to add a custom field to the Sprint Backlog Item type called "CurrentSprintEndDate", and update it thru a custom event handler that will change this field when the item's iteration path field changes. The you could write similar queries as you were doing above agains that field such as "CurrentSprintEndDate > @Today".

But that is a lot fo work for something that would seemingly be simple.

Comment: I agree that it's too much work.  I would think this should be something Conchango should do in the backend for their template.